# SharePoint Modal dialog page is empty

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, modal-dialog, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have tried creating a modal dialog in a SharePoint Hosted APP using this script but I am getting an empty page in the resulting modal dialog.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ShowDialog = function () {
        var options = {
            url: '/SitePages/Test.aspx',
            title: 'Modal',
            width: 640,
            height: 400,
            dialogReturnValueCallback: function(dialogResult, returnValue) {
                window.location.replace(returnValue);
            }
        };

        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    };
     //SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', ShowDialog);
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ShowDialog, "sp.ui.dialog.js","SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog");
</script>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I think you must pass in the full URL to the page you want to show

Comment: Yes I tried already...

Comment: Check your F12 browser Dev tools - there should be a error showing you what went wrong. Also check the `IFrame` created for the modal.